# Generate lines from given azimuth and points in GeoPandas

Tags: geometry, geopandas, shapely

I am reading a points shapefile containing the azimuth information in the attribute table, and I want to generate lines from these data. I have tried to use `shapely.Point` as a tool, however it can't read geodataframe but only given values.

Here is a sample of my data:

|  | lat | lon | Azimuth |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 22.969411 | 120.202380 | 165.0 |
| 1 | 22.969329 | 120.202314 | 55.370 |
| 2 | 22.969297 | 120.202294 | 5.0 |
| 3 | 22.968941 | 120.202245 | 145.0 |

Here is my code:

```
from shapely.geometry import Point, LineString

def cosdir(azim):
    az = np.radians(azim)
    cosa = np.sin(az)
    cosb = np.cos(az)
    return cosa,cosb

az = gdf['Azimuth']

point = Point(gdf['lon'],gdf['lat'])

cosa, cosb = cosdir(az)
print(cosa, cosb)
length = 10000

endline = Point(point.x(length*cosa), point.y+ +(length*cosb))
line = LineString([point,endline])
```

and here is the the response:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[124], line 12
      9 # dfp = pd.DataFrame(gdf)
     10 az = gdf['Azimuth']
---> 12 point = Point(gdf['經度'],gdf['緯度'])
     14 cosa, cosb = cosdir(az)
     15 print(cosa, cosb)

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\python\Lib\site-packages\shapely\geometry\point.py:73, in Point.__new__(self, *args)
     70     coords = np.array(args).squeeze()
     72 if coords.ndim > 1:
---> 73     raise ValueError(
     74         f"Point() takes only scalar or 1-size vector arguments, got {args}"
     75     )
     76 if not np.issubdtype(coords.dtype, np.number):
     77     coords = [float(c) for c in coords]

ValueError: Point() takes only scalar or 1-size vector arguments
```

So what should I do to read every value in the geodataframe and form lines from the data?

Comment: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
from shapely import Point, LineString
import numpy as np
import geopandas as gpd

length = 10000 #The length of the lines, in meters

#Create a geodataframe
data = {"lat":[22.969411, 22.969329, 22.969297, 22.968941],
        "lon":[120.202380, 120.202314, 120.202294, 120.202245],
        "Azimuth":[165, 55.370, 5, 145]}
df = gpd.pd.DataFrame(data=data)
geometry = gpd.points_from_xy(x=df["lon"], y=df["lat"], crs=4326)
df = gpd.GeoDataFrame(data=data, geometry=geometry, crs=4326)
df = df.to_crs(3829) #You need to have a projected coordinate system with meters as units, for example 3829

df.to_file(r"C:\GIS\data\testdata\input_points.shp") #Save the points

#Calculate end coordinates and create a line
df["endx"] = df.apply(lambda row: np.sin(np.radians(row["Azimuth"]))*length+row["geometry"].x, axis=1)
df["endy"] = df.apply(lambda row: np.cos(np.radians(row["Azimuth"]))*length+row["geometry"].y, axis=1)
df["line"] = df.apply(lambda row: LineString([row.geometry, Point(row["endx"], row["endy"])]), axis=1)

df = df.set_geometry("line").drop(columns="geometry").rename_geometry("geometry").set_crs(3829)
df.to_file(r"C:\GIS\data\testdata\lines.shp")
```

[image]